# Centos7 node-oracle connection failed error - Error: DPI-1047

Tags: oracle, centos, node-oracledb

I'm trying to install my web application on Centos7.
I've tested on my Windows and everything worked fine.

I've followed oracle instruction. However, it's impossible to connect to DB.

There's an already running program in the machine so I do not believe oracle is not installed as the error says. Please check blow and help.

Added into .bashrc:

1. export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/bcweb/oracleclient/instantclient_19_3

created oracleclient folder and added all the required file
2.

```
-r--r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall      5780  4월 17  2019 BASIC_LICENSE
-rw-r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall      1632  4월 17  2019 BASIC_README
-rw-r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall     41840  4월 17  2019 adrci
-rw-r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall     59296  4월 17  2019 genezi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bcweb oinstall        17  3월 29 08:18 libcintsh.so -> libclntsh.so.19.3
-rw-r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall        17  4월 17  2019 libclntsh.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall        17  4월 17  2019 libclntsh.so.10.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall        17  4월 17  2019 libclntsh.so.11.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall        17  4월 17  2019 libclntsh.so.12.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall        17  4월 17  2019 libclntsh.so.18.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall  79961792  4월 17  2019 libclntsh.so.19.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall   8041608  4월 17  2019 libclntshcore.so.19.1
-r--r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall   3609536  4월 17  2019 libipc1.so
-r--r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall    478432  4월 17  2019 libmql1.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall   6587832  4월 17  2019 libnnz19.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall        15  4월 17  2019 libocci.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall        15  4월 17  2019 libocci.so.10.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall        15  4월 17  2019 libocci.so.11.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall        15  4월 17  2019 libocci.so.12.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall        15  4월 17  2019 libocci.so.18.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall   2339896  4월 17  2019 libocci.so.19.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall 130515320  4월 17  2019 libociei.so
-r--r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall    153624  4월 17  2019 libocijdbc19.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall    115976  4월 17  2019 liboramysql19.so
drwxr-xr-x 3 bcweb oinstall        19  8월 27  2020 network
-rw-r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall   4210517  4월 17  2019 ojdbc8.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall   1680074  4월 17  2019 ucp.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall    236960  4월 17  2019 uidrvci
-rw-r--r-- 1 bcweb oinstall     74263  4월 17  2019 xstreams.jar
```

error:

```
Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html for help
Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html
You must have 64-bit Oracle client libraries in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or configured with ldconfig.
If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html

    at OracleDb.getConnection (/home/bcweb/web/backend/node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js:272:25)
    at OracleDb.getConnection (/home/bcweb/web/backend/node_modules/oracledb/lib/util.js:176:19)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to your Bash configuration files is a potential failure point - there are many places where this wouldn't have an effect.  It's better to use `ldconfig` as shown in the [node-oracledb installation instructions with Instant Client ZIP files](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#instzip).  However, if you have other Oracle software (such as the database itself) on your computer, then you wouldn't do this.  Update your question with more details if this is the case, and you want help.

Finally, Instant Client 19.10 is out, so there's no reason to still be using 19.3.